# React: How to wait on prop data before rendering child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, graphql, mapping

I have a parent component called Dashboard and child component called DashboardTable. I'm able to successfully make an async graphql call in the parent element and pass the data to the child component.

Problem: The props data takes a second to load so it returns undefined for a second before getting the data (verified using console.log()). That delay causes an error in the mapping function. Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Question: How do I make the render wait for the prop data to load before rendering. I tried a conditional like this `{this.props.data == undefined ? (wait) : (render)}` but that didn't work (same error).

Here is my code. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong

**DashboardTable (child)**

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/js/src/collapse.js";
import Navigation from "../Navigation";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { API } from "@aws-amplify/api";
import config from "../../aws-exports";
import * as queries from "../../graphql/queries";

export class DashboardTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

 

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.data.data); // !!this returns undefined one time then a second later it returns the props data I want :)

    return (
      <div>
        <div
          className="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 mx-auto"
          style={{ maxWidth: 900 }}
        >
          {this.props.data.data.map((opportunity) => (
            <div className="col mb-4">
              <div>
                <a href="#">
                  <img
                    className="rounded img-fluid shadow w-100 fit-cover"
                    src="assets/img/products/awsLogo.jpg"
                    style={{
                      height: 250,
                    }}
                  />
                </a>
                <div className="py-4">
                  <span
                    className="badge mb-2"
                    style={{ margin: 2, backgroundColor: "#ff9900" }}
                  >
                    {opportunity.interview_type}
                  </span>
                  <span
                    className="badge bg mb-2"
                    style={{ margin: 2, backgroundColor: "#ff9900" }}
                  >
                    4
                  </span>
                  <span
                    className="badge bg mb-2"
                    style={{ margin: 2, backgroundColor: "#ff9900" }}
                  >
                    Reverse
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default DashboardTable;
```

***Dashboard (parent) This works. It passes the graphql data to the child***

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "bootstrap/js/src/collapse.js";
import DashboardTable from "../DashboardTable";
import { API } from "@aws-amplify/api";
import config from "../../aws-exports";
import * as queries from "../../graphql/queries";

export default function Dashboard() {
  API.configure(config);

  async function asyncCall() {
    const gqlreturn = await API.graphql({
      query: queries.listMockOppsTables,
    });
    // console.log(gqlreturn.data.listMockOppsTables); // result: { "data": { "listTodos": { "items": [/* ..... */] } } }
    return gqlreturn;
  }

  // initialize with empty array
  const [opportunityTable, changeOpportunityTable] = useState([]);
  //console.log(opportunityTable); // this works! returns a promise

  // call api to fetch data on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await asyncCall();

      changeOpportunityTable(response);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <section className="py-5 mt-5">
        <div className="container py-5">
          <h2 className="fw-bold text-center">
            Your upcoming shadowing events
            <br />
            <br />
          </h2>

          <DashboardTable data={opportunityTable}></DashboardTable>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this:

```js
{ oppotrunityTable && opportynityTable.length ?
  <DashboardTable data={opportunityTable}></DashboardTable>
  : null
}
```

But you have an error, not because of this but because your data is undefined! Check your data!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This got rid of the error but now nothing in the child component runs include console.log("helloworld")

Comment: Yes!! because your data is wrong? Check your opportunityTable by console.log() in your parent component))

Comment: You're correct. Sorry I didn't understand initially. I fixed by data and now see it in the console in the parent but the child is still not showing. Any ideas?

Comment: Show what data in opportunityTable??

Comment: The opportunityTable is a json data from graphql. The issue seems to be that the opportunity.length state is not updating. I replaced the null in the snippet you sent with the <h1>hello</h1> and it just shows "hello" that forever

Comment: like this  {opportunityTable && opportunityTable.length ? (
            <DashboardTable data={opportunityTable}></DashboardTable>
          ) : (
            <h1>hello</h1>
          )}

Comment: if your array data in opportunityTable.data you need to change your state and change your condition to: opportynityTable.data && opportunityTable.data.length

Comment: becouse i think your opportunityTable is not array))